# Incjet touch event from service on Android

Tags: android, service, touch

I have a project for college and can't find the answer so far. I have a small aplication doesnt matter what it does , it has couple of buttons for example. 
What i have to do is make a simple service with server that gets two coordinates and injects the touch event on that coordinates in my aplication.

I can simulate (inject) touch event in activity easily :

```
            MotionEvent event1 = MotionEvent.obtain(1, 1, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 120,200, 0);

            MotionEvent event2 = MotionEvent.obtain(1, 1, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 120,200, 0);

                        MainView.dispatchTouchEvent(event1);
            MainView.dispatchTouchEvent(event2);
```

This works fine. Now i need to somehow send the MainView to the service and perfom dispatchTouchEvent on it when the coordinates come to the server. Any ideas how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Send a broadcast from the service.
E.g.

```
Intent data = new Intent(ACTION);
data.putExtra("action", DISPATCH_MOTION_EVENT);
data.putExtra("x", [... from server ...]);
data.putExtra("y", [... from server ...]);
sendBroadcast(data);
```

In your activity you register a new Receiver which reacts on this broadcast event and dispatches your event.

Check this: [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: This is exactly what i need. I'll check broadcastReceiver article and try it. Thanks :) !